# In MongoDB how do you use $set to update a nested value by using a dynamic value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For example, consider a collection photos with the following document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"),
  name: "foo",
  photos: {before:[], after:[]}
}
```

How do I update the photos document if i had to receive a json object from front-end that would be like this :

```
{
   imageType: "before", 
   photo: [ 'base64URI' ]
}
```

Here the value of "imageType" can be "before" or "after".
What will be the $set query ?

I tried `photos.${req.imageType}` i expected that this would be evaluated to a string but it gave me error -->**Property assignment expected**

Comment: This can be done at the server side itself, just check what is the value of `imageType` and create a `$set` value conditionally.

Comment: Can you explain this is more detail. A query example would be nice.

Comment: What language are you using on the server side where the request comes?

Comment: Typescript for backend and Dart for frontend. But how does that have to do with my mongodb query? I just want to know if we can use a dynamic query.

Comment: In typescript, you can check whether `req.imageType === 'before'` then `{$set: { "photo.before": req.phoho}}`, otherwise set `photo.after` .